# Image position of sprite image in fabric canvas

Tags: fabricjs

I'm not able to position the center image of the sprite image in fabric canvas.when i use the clipto function the image size becomes small.Is there way to position an image in background url in fabric js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>fabric</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/test/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
 fabric.Image.fromURL('/test/bike6x6_big.jpg', function(img) {
  canvas.add(img);
  },{
  width:480,
  height:327,
  top: 0 ,
  left: 0,
  clipTo:function(ctx){
    ctx.rect(0, 0 , 60, 60);
  }
});    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[clipped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4wJV.png)
Expected output:
[image onload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FRkG.png)
For the entire sprite image you can visit spritesheet demo of the spritespin.genie.au

Comment: Can you explain more, what you want?